# Transform position vector uses some random value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am changing position of my button (X and Y).

I change position with `transform.position`

```
devButton.transform.position = new Vector2(780, 620)
```

but instead setting x = 780 and y = 620 it sets it to -500 and -100. When i delete that line it doesn't affect button position so i know it is not getting that value from anywhere else.

Screenshots in comments

Ok, i got some clue. It is getting position of Canvas (currently 1280, 720) and then it calculate it Canvas X - X from vector i set up. Same for Y and i do not have idea why is it doing that.

Comment: Are you sure its localPosition is not -500, -100?

Comment: what do you mean by localPosition?

Comment: There are two properties of a transform, its position and its localPosition - if it is the child of an object, you may be looking at the localPosition property by accident

Comment: where i can see that localPosition. Button is child of canvas, but in script i am targeting button. I sad that line i wrote change position but to other values, when i delete line, it stays in place

Comment: You want to put a screenshot of your problem? That would be helpful

Comment: @Programmer

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vW2e.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMe58.jpg)
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JECdh.jpg)

image 1 - No running, you can see default values
image 2 - Running with transform line ON
image 3 - Running with transform line OFF

Comment: What you mean by "Running with transform line OF" is when you comment this line: `devButton.transform.position = new Vector2(780, 620)`?

Comment: @Programmer Yes. I just got something. Going to update post in about 2 min. Maby it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it and here is solution:

First of all, i found out that for some reason when i change position, it for some reason subtract my X and Y values by Canvas current posX and posY, so when i want to change position I add canvas posX to my X and canvas posY to my Y. So it goes something like this

```
GameObject canvas;
float canvasPosX;
float canvasPosY;

private void Awake()
{
    canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");

    canvasPosX = canvas.transform.position.x;
    canvasPosY = canvas.transform.position.y;

    gameobject.transform.position = new Vector2(myX + canvasPosX, myY + canvasPosY)
}
```

Still i do not know why canvas position has any connection with button position but i found out that this works good for me :)

Comment: I recommend reading the script manual. Once you understand the distinction between `transform.position` and `transform.localPosition`, the reason "why canvas position has any connection with button position" should become more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the position of **UI** elements using the NGUI system, it's not that easy unfortunately.

First, you have to use the `RectTransform` component instead of the traditionnal `Transform`.

Then, you have to indicate whether the element has any stretching behavior or not. Stretching behavior happens when the anchorMin and anchorMax properties are not identical.

> For a non-stretching Rect Transform, the position is set most easily by setting the anchoredPosition and the sizeDelta properties. The anchoredPosition specifies the position of the pivot relative to the anchors. The sizeDelta is just the same as the size when there’s no stretching.
>
> For a stretching Rect Transform, it can be simpler to set the position using the offsetMin and offsetMax properties. The offsetMin property specifies the corner of the lower left corner of the rect relative to the lower left anchor. The offsetMax property specifies the corner of the upper right corner of the rect relative to the upper right anchor.

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html

About the difference between the values you give, and the values which are set, it's surely because the anchors are not positioned as you are expecting.  But without any further information, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Where do you see NGUI in this question?

Comment: The poster talks about "Button", and with values that big, I assume the poster tries to place a button on a Canvas. And, read carefully my answer : "**If** you are trying to set the position of UI elements using the NGUI"

Comment: Yes, it is canvas.

Comment: I asked because I didn't see any statement or code that has anything to do with NGUI. Button can be Unity's uGUI Button.

Comment: Although definitely not explicitly indicated as NGUI, it's unlikely to be related to the legacy GUI because that variant of the Button element does not have a `transform` property.